# How to use SAS to split a string into two variables

Tags: sas, dataset

1. I have a dataset as below:

   ```
   country
   United States, Seattle
   United Kingdom, London
   ```

How can I split country into a data in SAS like:

```
    country                  city
    United States           Seattle
    United Kingdom          London
```

Comment: BTW, googling for answers to such kind of questions is much faster and more educational then asking on forums;)

Comment: On the other hand, this becomes more true when more people nevertheless ask these questions on forums...

Answer (score 17):

Use function SCAN() with comma as separator.

```
data test;
  set test;
  city=scan(country,2,',');
  country=scan(country,1,',');
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, `INFILE magic` (google the term for papers on the topic); useful for parsing many variables from one string and/or dealing with quoted fields and such that would be more work with `scan`.

```
filename tempfile "c:\temp\test.txt";


data have;
input @1 country $50.;
datalines;
United States, Seattle
United Kingdom, London
;;;;
run;

data want;
set have;
infile tempfile dlm=',' dsd;
input @1 @@;
_infile_=country;
format newcountry city $50.;
input newcountry $ city $ @@;
run;
```

`tempfile` can be any file (or one you create on the fly with any character in it to avoid premature EOF).

Answer (score 0):

Response to:

```
data test;
  set test;
  city=scan(country,2,',');
  country=scan(country,1,',');
run;
```

What if I want to split the **last comma** in the string only, keeping 7410 City?

Example: "Junior 18, Plays Piano, 7410 City